# Reading very old dates from MySQL on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I needed to store in a MySQL table dates with only a day and a month (they define abstract periods that can be "attached" to a year later). I found it cleaner to use the DATETIME field type rather than, for example, an integer. So I decided to store all dates with the same, very old, year. MySQL DATETIME field starts at year 1000, so I picked the year 1004 (because I may have to store a 02-29 value in these fields and 1000 is not a leap year).

I put this value in a PHP DateTime object and displays only the month and day parts on my page. Basically, I'm doing this :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateInDb);
echo $date->format('m-d');
```

This works fine on my development server (Debian 7 / PHP 5.6 / Mysql 5.5), and in several production environments all on Linux, with various PHP 5.6+ and MySQL/MariaDB versions)

I have only one production environment on Windows (PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7 in a XAMPP). On this environment, the dates are properly stored in the database, but when I display the month/day in my page, I always get 01/01, as if the value was somehow translated into a default timestamp.

Replacing the year 1004 with something more recent, like 2000, fixes this. That's an acceptable solution for me, I don't really care what year is stored, since I don't use it anyway (I used this trick only to make it clear for future me that the year was useless)

I'm only looking for an explanation on the cause, to satisfy my curiosity, and because it may be helpful to someone else in the future who really needs the old dates ! Is this a known bug ?

Comment: I guess it has to do with start ranges. Some stuff about dates start at 1901, others at 1970. But explaining why it works on Linux but not on Windows...

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($date);` on Windows? Because with Windows/PHP 7.2 I get what I expect even for year 1004. Also see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#95610) - it mentions theoretical limits to be "-9999-01-01" through "9999-12-31" on PHP 5.2.9 on Windows Vista 64. (Edit: the negative limit is actually -9999 to -1000 - values closer to zero seem to be interpreted as timezone offset somehow. For positive values the usable range seems to be 100 to 9999.)

Comment: I don't have access to my client's server. I asked them to perform the test, but they didn't. And since their problem is solved, I guess they never will...